# namespace is referenced without import declaration

Tags: c++, xsd

I am following this tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11057/XSD-Using-the-include-element-for-schematic-reuse

When I compile the XSD,

/xsd/xsd-3.2.0-x86_64/bin/xsd cxx-tree --hxx-suffix .h --cxx-suffix .cpp --generate-default-ctor  Demo.xsd
demo_include.xsd:2:56: error: namespace 'http://www.demo.com' is referenced without import declaration
demo_include.xsd:6:68: error: namespace 'http://www.demo.com' is referenced without import declaration
Demo.xsd:3:46: error: namespace 'http://www.demo.com' is referenced without import declaration
Demo.xsd:7:58: error: namespace 'http://www.demo.com' is referenced without import declaration
Demo.xsd:18:64: error: namespace 'http://www.demo.com' is referenced without import declaration

Question: why xsd complains the namespace of 'http://www.demo.com'?

Thank you

XSD: http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/xsd/c++/parser/

Comment: have you found the solution?